# samples size chm php manual

Tags: php, chm

Please look at the image showing very small PHP code blocks:

[image]

I downloaded this CHM file from:

https://www.php.net/get/php_manual_en.chm/from/a/mirror

But I have a problem with the font size of sample code. My system is Windows 7/64bit.

How do I increase the font size?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the following steps:
open PHP Manual CHM file than go to "Options->Internet Options->Click on General Tab->Click on Accessibility button->check the option for 'Ignore font sizes specified on webpages'->Than press OK button."

Follow the screenshot:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now you can see your php manual examples in normal size like below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error shown. Downloading the file `php_manual_en.chm` from the link above shows everything correctly.

Internet Explorer settings have a direct effect on the display in CHM.
Please clear the cache of Internet Explorer **and / or** reset all Internet options to the default settings (**please be careful!**) as a first step.

*Another thought:* The hh.dat file stores user-specific information on all the HTMLHelp files (*.CHM) on your system (position, favourite topics, search history, etc.), and may cause a error if it has somehow been corrupted.

Delete or rename the file hh.dat to reset all (!) CHM windows on your system to their default settings as a second step. Windows will create a new version of hh.dat when you next open any .chm file. You should find hh.dat at:

Windows 7: \Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\HTML Help

The PHP code blocks are formatted with css for syntax highlighting. So check if you special settings in your environment.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in Windows 7. Installing Internet Explorer 11 solved the problem but there are still some little CSS incompatibilities and I think it is not unexpected in year 2023 while using old OS.

Comment: Support for IE 11 has ended more than a year ago

Comment: @NicoHaase We are not talknig about IE 11 Support. This is the reason why PHP Manual is showing incorrectly. You are free to use native IE8 and do not update to IE11 and also use CHM how it appears.